# Qt: Settting the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable to point to your Android NDK

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk

What directory will give it access in Qt. I currently have it at this root directory when it asks me for it:

**C:\Users\me\Dev\Qt\android-ndk-r11c**

Which is the directory you get when you directly extract the Android NDK for my system at: 
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

And I receive the error:

> Project ERROR: You need to set the ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment
>   variable to point to your Android NDK. Could not read qmake
>   configuration file
>   C:/QtAndroid/5.6/msvc2015_64/mkspecs/android-g++/qmake.conf. Error
>   while parsing file C:\Users\me\Dev\Qt\ImaQtPi\ImaQtPi.pro.
>   Giving up.

Comment: Are you trying to build from Qt Creator ?

Comment: Yes it is working now. =/ I need to edit post. I'm not actually sure what fixed it sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file wasn't the correct NDK file. I downloaded the NDK for 32 bit on accident. What a silly mistake.

Make sure you get the correct NDK from the website!

Other than that it is pretty easy just unzip it and that directory is the root directory. Simple as that.

Answer (score -1):

ANDROID_NDK_ROOT must point to C:\Users\me\Dev\Qt\android-ndk-r11c without final \ .

Comment: What do you mean? it is already C:\Users\me\Dev\Qt\android-ndk-r11c without a following \       do you mean just C:\Users\me\Dev\Qt

Comment: Your environment PATH must point to folder with android-ndk, in you case C:\Users\me\Dev\Qt\android-ndk-r11c . For more info how add to path [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)